# Unity editor freezes when running a certain function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a function that will run until an images fillamount is at 0. However when I call this function from another class the unity editor completing freezes. I cant even stop pause play mode.

**The class that calls the cooldown function.**

```
Cooldown cooldown;
    
cooldown = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Cooldown>();//Sets cooldown to have the same values as the prefab.
    
    public void gatherCooldown()
    {
        cooldown.resourceCooldown();
    }
```

**Cooldown Class**

```
public class Cooldown : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image imageCooldown;
    public float cooldown = 5;
    public bool isCooldown

    public void resourceCooldown()
    {
        while (imageCooldown.fillAmount >= 0)
        {
            imageCooldown.fillAmount -= 1 / cooldown * Time.deltaTime;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm far from a Unity expert, but shouldn't you have some delay in your while loop?

Because if deltatime is close enough to 0, wouldn't that means you have a near infinite loop ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Running a blocking method like that is nearly never a good idea, as it has to stop the execution of everything else. I suspect your method should be a Coroutine instead

Comment: i just want to have the player remain in the same position until the images fill amount is 0 then destroy that object. I tried to use a coroutine but I'm new and kinda got confused by them

Comment: did not even read the code, but freeze = infinite loop. You need to be careful using whiles and ensure that the code moves on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` is freezing the main thread.

This should probably rather be a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```
public class Cooldown : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image imageCooldown;
    public float cooldown = 5;
    public bool isCooldown;

    private IEnumerator CooldownRoutine()
    {
        isCooldown = true;

        while (imageCooldown.fillAmount >= 0)
        {
            imageCooldown.fillAmount -= 1 / cooldown * Time.deltaTime;

            // Tells Unity to "pause" this routine, render this frame
            // And continue from here in the next frame
            yield return null;
        }

        isCooldown = false;
    }

    public void resourceCooldown()
    {
        StartCoroutin(CooldownRoutine ());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the courtine worked. I tried something similar to this earlier and didn't see to work so thanks so much for both of your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using a blocking method. To fix that you could use a [`Corountine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) instead to decreasing your images `fillAmount`.

**Coroutine Example:**

```cs
private IEnumerator DecreaseFillAmount() {
    // Entered the Coroutine
    isCooldown = true;
    // Repeat until the fillAmount is smaller than or equal to 0
    while (imageCooldown.fillAmount > 0) {
        imageCooldown.fillAmount -= (1 / cooldown) * Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    // Left the Coroutine
    isCooldown = false;
}
```

You also need to make sure that you call your Coroutin the right way, you achieve this with `StartCoroutine()`.

**Calling the Coroutine:**

```cs
public void resourceCooldown() {
    // Call the DecreaseFillAmount Coroutine.
    StartCoroutine(DecreaseFillAmount());
}
```